# Receving notice: array to string conversion when using jquery autocomplete

Tags: php, html, jquery-autocomplete, forms

I am using jquery autocomplete on a form and trying to do a simple echo of what is selected upon submitting a form entry to verify my data is being read correctly. I am receiving the following message:

Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\New\search.php on line 4
Array

Search.php Contents:

```
<?php

$dest_name = $_GET["dest_name"];
echo ["dest_name"];

?>
```

Html contnts:

```
<body>
<form method="GET" action="search.php">
    <div>
    <input type="text" id ="destination" name="dest_name"/>
    </div>
</form
</body>
```

autocomplete script

```
var destinations = [
        {value: "49 Degrees North Ski Area",label: "49 Degrees North Ski Area",id: "1"},
        {value: "Afton Alps",label: "Afton Alps",id: "2"},
        {value: "Al Quaal Recreation Ski Area",label: "Al Quaal Recreation Ski Area",id: "3"},
        {value: "Alpental",label: "Alpental",id: "4"},
        {value: "Alpine Meadows",label: "Alpine Meadows",id: "5"},
];

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#destination").autocomplete({
        source: destinations,
        focus: function(event, ui) {
            $("#destination").val(ui.item.label);
            return false;
        },
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $("#destination").val(ui.item.label);
            $("#dest_id").val(ui.item.id);
            return false;
        }
    });
    $('#button').click(function() {
        alert($("#dest_id").val());
    });
});
```

Comment: Why is it 
`echo ["dest_name"];` 
and not 
`echo $dest_name;` ? 
`[]` is the new array syntax in PHP 5.4. You can create a new array by
`$arr = [1, 2, 3];`

Comment: Yeah, I was overlooking that. I was able to get it working. Changed it to $dest_name = $_GET["dest_name"];
echo $dest_name;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In line 4 use have displayed the array index instead of that you have to echo the variable which you have declared in line 3.i.e.,

echo $dest_name;

Answer (score 0):

On line 4 of your PHP file you are echoing an array (the square brackets can be used to create an array):

```
echo ["dest_name"];
```

If you want to echo the brackets, you need to wrap the entire line in quotes.

```
echo '["dest_name"]';
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was able to get it working by changing my php as follows: $dest_name = $_GET["dest_name"];
echo $dest_name;